# Making a CustomView with a static vertical size in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm making a document viewer in Objective-C, I want to have a bar at the top of the page with a bunch of buttons in it which open up menus, change pages, etc. At the moment I'm using a custom view which then just has all of the buttons inside it, but my problem is that it isn't a static vertical height, so when the window resizes it changes the size of the custom view rather than my PDFView. Is there a way I can stop it from resizing, or is there a better method I should be using to create a menu?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With auto layout, you can just give the view a fixed height -- from the editor menu, choose Pin, then Height. Make sure that it then only has one vertical constraint, either to the top, bottom, or centerY.

Comment: I've got the custom view selected when I pin it, and it puts the constraint on the custom view, but then the whole window gets locked for some reason. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @ahansen, what do you mean, the "whole window gets locked"?

Comment: Oh right that was a poor explanation, sorry. I mean that the containing window can no longer be resized vertically when it is running, or in the editor.

Comment: @ahansen, are you sure that the view doesn't have a constraint to both the top and bottom of the window? If it does, delete the bottom one.

Comment: It was because the windows underneath it were sitting directly on the edge. Got it working now, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Auto-layout ? You may have to play with it.

Without seeing the code it's hard to debug the problem. Post the snippet where you're re-sizing the views if you're not using auto-layout.

Comment: I'm using the drap and drop style interface if that's what you mean. I might just try playing around and making sure things are snapping in the right places.